# Oracle using dynamic sql when table name is a parameter

Tags: oracle, dynamic-sql

I have a SQL query (a store procedure )  that i want to convert to PLSQL
I already conver most of the store procedure but i cant convert the following part :

```
DECLARE lookupTableRow CURSOR FOR
  SELECT TableName FROM SYS_LookUpTable
  OPEN lookupTableRow
  FETCH NEXT FROM lookupTableRow INTO @tableName
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
  BEGIN

  SET @sql='SELECT * FROM '+@tableName
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

  IF @counter=0
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO T_TABLE_MAPPING VALUES('P_MAIN_METADATA', 'Table', @tableName)
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO T_TABLE_MAPPING 
      VALUES(  'P_MAIN_METADATA', 
               'Table' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),@counter), 
               @tableName)
  END

  SET @counter=@counter+1
  FETCH NEXT FROM lookupTableRow INTO @tableName
  END
  CLOSE lookupTableRow
  DEALLOCATE lookupTableRow
```

As i understand i can't use ORACLE dynamic sql (execute immediate) when the table name is a parameter.

Furthermore when i execute this dynamic query in my SQL store procedure each SELECT statement return me as a result the relevant table rows , those result are different in each loop .

Please advice for any solution
* how can i use dynamic sql with table name as parameter ?
* how can i use a "dynamic" cursor, in order to be able to display the dynamic results ?

Thanks for the advice

Comment: what does this `'Table' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),@counter)` do on this code?

Comment: It appears you're trying to obfuscate actual table names and assign them a name of Table# in a T_TableMapping.  if so would something like this work? `Select owner, table_name, 'Table' || to_char(rownum)  from all_tables order by owner, table_name`

Comment: But on SQL the following code is a SELECT statement .
This SELECT is changing on each loop .
The tables result from the SELECT are fill into a data set (in the c# code) 

So i need to find a way to how to do this :

SET @sql='SELECT * FROM '+@tableName
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

Comment: @RefaelCohen `I have a SQL query (a store procedure )` SQL is programming language which is industry standard for many RDBMS. You probably mean Transact-SQL or T-SQL stored procedure which is part of MS SQL Server product. Please use proper terms to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you don't know how to do here is using a table name dynamically then this is how you can accomplish that

```
  1  declare
  2     n number;
  3     table_name varchar2(30) := 'dual';
  4  begin
  5     execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || table_name into n;
  6     dbms_output.put_line(n);
  7* end;
SQL> /
1
```

Comment: I solve this problem in the "old way"

I ran this select statement : SELECT TableName FROM SYS_LookUpTable
In order to see all the relevant table name 

Then i simple create a select statement for each table name 

Yes i know that this not the elegant way, and i know that i wrote about 41 select statement in order to achieve the same result like i get in the sql server

But i didnt find other way to do this simple query in ORACLE

Comment: I wouldent say its ugly in oracle. Maybe say what you are trying to do and we can help you get there in "the oracle way"

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to populate a table that obfuscates table names to something else, why do it sequentially forcing the db to change contexts and slow down?

```
Create table t_table_mapping as 
(    Select 'P_MAIN_METADATA' "P_MAIN_METADATA", 
      'Table' || to_char(rownum) as "Table", table_name 
     from all_tables)
```

However this doesn't take into account schema names so what owner.  So you need to add a where clause to limit to the specific schema you're wanting to do this for.